# Windows localhost file path for Pandas.read_csv()

Tags: python, windows, pandas

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

I'm having trouble setting this up to read from a local file on my Windows machine (Win 10 EE). I tried:

`http://127.0.0.1/my/path`and `http://10.0.2.2/my/path`

Neither worked, so I explicitly opened port 8888 (not sure if it's a good one to open) and tried `local_ip:8888/my/path`

All of these return an error saying my machine refused the connection.

I'm probably misunderstanding something simple here, but I'm not sure what it is and Google isn't helping.

Comment: read a file HOW? where? unless you're running a webserver on your own machine, you can't do `http://127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @MarcB read a large csv file in chunks. I don't understand what you mean by "how"... the parameters are all in the Pandas docs and I referenced the method I'm using explicitly. "Where" is obviously in a local folder on my machine.

Comment: well, where are you running pandas? if it's on some remote server, then `127.0.0.1` means "talk to myself" for the server, and will never hit your machine. if it's on your machine, then you need to have a webserver running locally so that this url can be served up, blah blah blah

Comment: just use regular file path instead of url's: `df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/input.csv', ...)`

Comment: @MarcB so are you saying I just can't use this function to read in a local csv file unless I setup a web server on my machine?

Comment: @MaxU Ha! This totally works!

Comment: @AutomaticStatic, sure it works, that's why the parameter called `filepath_or_buffer` ;)

Comment: @MaxU I was just confused by the docs. Thanks.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic, you are welcome. :)

Comment: when i read my data using the parameter which @MaxU said and print the return value, it is the titanic dataset not my data :(. i am really confused